# IOS UICollectionView Sample

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am working about sample function use UICollectionView.
I used this code to get all images from document folder:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *myPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *directoryContents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:myPath error:nil];
NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];
    [subpredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH '.png'"]];
    [subpredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH '.jpg'"]];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];

NSArray *onlyImages = [directoryContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

I already NSLog onlyImages and have all images from document folder.

After that, I want it will show UICollectionView.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog(@"onlyImagesComplete: %@", onlyImages);
    return onlyImages.count;

}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *identifier = @"collectionCell";

    CollectionCellShowImages *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.collectionCellImages setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    NSLog(@"onlyImages: %@", onlyImages);
    cell.collectionCellImages.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[onlyImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;

}
```

But, it not work.

Edited:
[image]

That is, I created cell for UICollectionView.

Comment: What doesn't work?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: No error! It not show images in collectionView

Comment: Did you using the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` ? Did you set the `itemSize`?

Comment: I used this code to set Cell size:
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}

Comment: Post your `CollectionCellShowImages` class

Comment: @VõMaiTrinh Did you use `registerNib`?

Comment: Of course!
[self.collectionShowImages setDelegate:self];
    [self.collectionShowImages setDataSource:self];
    [self.collectionShowImages registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionCellShowImages" bundle:nil]   forCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"collectionCell"];

Comment: @VõMaiTrinh Can you post your project on GitHub?

Comment: No! My project have some another function.

Comment: I cannot post my project on GitHub.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81589/discussion-between-bannings-and-vo-mai-trinh).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I had fixed this problem.

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it :)

Comment: Maybe he forgot to use the fullpath for each files. because it seems that contentsOfDirectoryAtPath returns only the filenames. right?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *identifier = @"collectionCell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[onlyImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [[cell.contentView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]; 


    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure,you did't mistyped your `UICollectionViewCell` identifier put label on it to test it,check your `ImageView` height and width if you are using autolayout .